# Install4J MacOS notarization fails with Apple ID account attached to other iTunes providers

Tags: macos, installation, install4j

I am using Install4J 8 on a macOS machine to create a Mac installer for a Java application notarized. I enabled checkbox for notarization. During build Install4J prompts for AppleId and password. I have generated an application password for my apple id and provided it to Install4J but get following error.

```
Stack trace:
com.exe4j.a.d: could not upload myinstaller_macos_1_0_0.dmg: Your Apple ID account is attached to other iTunes providers. You will need to specify which provider you intend to submit content to by using the -itc_provider command. Please contact us if you have questions or need help. (1627) (code 1627)
    at com.install4j.d.a.f$c.a(ejt:136)
    at com.install4j.d.a.f.a(ejt:69)
    at com.install4j.b.r.b(ejt:192)
    at com.install4j.gui.b.run(ejt:100)

Any help will be appreciated in this matter.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you upgrade to 8.0.3, you can configure notarization on the "General Settings->Code signing" step and there is a text field "Provider short name" on that step that is passed to the `-itc_provider` argument.

Comment: Can you please help me what I need to put in "Provider short name" text field?

Comment: I am looking at https://indiestack.com/2019/09/notarization-provider-ids/ and going to try following command.
xcrun iTMSTransporter -m provider -u <yourAppleID> -p <yourAppSpecificPasswo>

Comment: I can confirm using above command and version 8.0.3 to provide -itc_provider has solved the problem.